# jEdit buffertabs one for all views

Tags: jedit

I normally use two views (split panes) in my jEdit. I also like to use BufferTabs. On my last computer I was able to have one BufferTabs section below the tow views from which I could change both view (depending on which was active). Now with the new installation I have a BufferTab for each view.
Does anybody know how to get the single BufferTab back?

Answer (score 0):

I use jEdit and BufferTabs for ages and to be honest, I've never seen the behaviour that you describe. If you are really sure you have seen this behaviour, do you by chance still have your settings directory of the old computer around?

Comment: I don't think I have. I saved the jEdit files, but there seems to be nothing that helps. Do you know where I might find the settings?

Comment: With settings directory I meant the jEdit settings directory. Where this is located depends on your platform and version. On older jEdit you will likely have found it in ~/.jedit, on later jEdit and Windows, it would be in %APPDATA%/jEdit. Those files if you have, you should have all settings and stuff, nothing - except maybe some 3rd-party external tools used by some plugins that have their own locations - should write outside of that folder. So if you let your jEdit run against this settings directory with -settings=/path/to/old/settings, you will see whether it is like you think it was. :-)